# Does anyone know why this exception is being thrown in ios/cordova?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I'm working on a hybrid app with a custom InAppBrowser plugin and seemingly randomly an exception gets thrown.

I don't have any way to consistently reproduce this bug. I open that app and browser around and eventually when clicking my browser plugin's close button this will happen.

It happens within cordova after I call this line here
[image: code that triggers this]

Where the exception actually happens
`CordovaLib.xcodeproj/Classes/Commands/CDVCommandDelegateImpl.m`
[image: cordova exception]
[image: xcode logs]

I have spent hours trying to find what is happening and I can't find any information online that helps. I've tried wrapping it in a try/catch to at least see if I can bypass it and that doesn't work either

The actual logged error is:

`*** Assertion failure in -[DDWebKitOperation dealloc], /SourceCache/MobileDataDetectorsUI/MobileDataDetectorsUI-109.1/URLification/DDOperation.m:202
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Container should already be nil'`

Does anyone know what could be causing this and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi,Have you found any solution for this problem i am also facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this crash in UIView's that use data detectors. In my case it was in a unit test, so the fix was to delete the data detector in the test.